# Can I use redirect-ssl to enable SSL on IONOS hosting?

Tags: ssl, nuxt.js

Trying to redirect the http domain to https, as google pages shows the http link in the search results rather than the https one.

Tried to use the redirect-ssl library with several different setups. Firstly `npm install redirect-ssl` with this in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
import redirectSSL from "redirect-ssl";

export default {
  serverMiddleware: [
    redirectSSL.create({
      enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
     }),
  ],
}
```

and also tried just this after `npm install redirect-ssl` in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  serverMiddleware: ["redirect-ssl"]
}
```

I was wondering if maybe this doesn't work because it's a static site, but I'm new to development so am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is good so far since it followed the documentation: https://github.com/unjs/redirect-ssl#using-with-nuxtjs

If you have http issues with your registrar or in your platform dashboard/server configuration, the issue should be fixed there and not in the code. `redirect-ssl` won't be able to help here IMO.

Where do you host your app?

Comment: It's a website hosted with ionos. I've just redone the website as it used to not have an SSL certificate so I was wondering if the Google crawler is just used to it being an http page

Comment: If it's static, you could host it for free on a lot of places: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/netlify-deployment If you want to stay on Ionos, you need to buy an SSL certificate: https://www.ionos.com/security/ssl-certificate Or try to setup your own: https://www.ionos.com/help/ssl-certificates/ Still, you don't need to pay for a static site hosting usually, so I'm not sure that you need to struggle for SSL + hosting fees. Go Netlify and enjoy. Google will crawl your website, notice that it's https and be happy again. You don't really have to do anything about it to my knowledge.